# Static menu in the Yii 2.0 advanced template back-end

Tags: ajax, menu, yii2, partial-views, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii 2.0 advanced template, and in the back-end want to have something like this:

[image]

A menu of the left that should contains items, and when clicking on those items the corresponding pages to be open on the right. The menu of the left should be static and to not lose focus when items are clicked.

This means that I will probably need to use partial views? Is there some extension/widget that is doing what I need? I'm new in Yii so I'm really not sure how to solve this. Any suggestion or idea will be appreciated. I'm sure I'm not the only one that need this in Yii, but could not find something on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is use layout.  You can define a layout with the menu on the the left and the main page in rest of the page.

this could be a layout sample eg: 'mylayout.php'

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/dfenx.ico" type="image/x-icon" />   
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php
            NavBar::begin([
                'brandLabel' => $this->title = Yii::$app->name ,
                'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                'brandOptions' =>[
                    'style' => 'font-family: palatino; font-size:24px;'
                ],
                'options' => [
                    //'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
                    'class' => 'navbar-default navbar-fixed-top',
                ],
            ]);
            $menuItems = [
                ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
            ];
            if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/user/register']];
                $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/user/login']];
            } else {
                $menuItems[] = [
                    'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    'url' => ['/user/logout'],
                    'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
                ];
            }
            echo Nav::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
                'items' => $menuItems,
            ]);
            NavBar::end();
        ?>

        <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
            <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3' >
                    <!-- here your left menu -->
            </div>
             <div class='col-lg-9 col-md-9' >
                <!-- here your content page-->
                <?= $content ?>
            </div>       
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-left">&copy; Digital FenX <?= date('Y') ?></p>
        <p class="pull-right"><?php // Yii::powered() ?></p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

in the controller you can set the layout you want use in this way

```
public function actionYourAction()
{

   $this->layout = 'mylayout';
   return $this->render(ourView', [
        'model'                 =>$model,
        'dataProvider'                => $provider,
    ]);
}
```